# how to convert object to array excluding dependencies in php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

So i know how to convert an object into an array using typecast as follows :

```
$Arr = (array) $object;
```

But the above method as we know includes child objects/dependencies.

Now is there a way to avoid these dependencies when typecasting / converting objects to array?
Maybe something similar to the magic method __sleep() used when serialising objects?

Comment: [What / why are you doing that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I wanted to handle the caching of the object within the objects class. So when the object cache is retrieved (as object) i want to convert it to an array so i can loop through it and assign the class properties based on the key => value pair. For which I wanted to eliminate the dependencies/child objects when converting to an array

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$object->toArray();` form, and declare a `toArray()` method, for example:

```
public function toArray()
{
    return array(
        "myvar1" => $this->myvar1,
        "myvar2" => $this->myvar2,
    );
}
```